# Not able to use the json data

Tags: javascript, json

I am using a PHP script to generate JSON string and I want to use this in a javascript to display some data. The problem is that I am not able to use access the json string data even after using json.parse. Please help me out.

The JSON string is:

```
{
    "8": {
        "dept_name": null,
        "dept_code": null,
        "int_jour": null,
        "nat_jour": null,
        "inter_nat_conf": null,
        "nat_conf": null,
        "int_book_chap": null,
        "nat_book_chap": null
    },
    "0": {
        "int_jour": 10,
        "nat_jour": 1,
        "inter_nat_conf": 16,
        "nat_conf": 14,
        "int_book_chap": 1,
        "nat_book_chap": 4,
        "dept_code": "101",
        "dept_name": "ECE"
    },
    "1": {
        "int_jour": 22,
        "nat_jour": 1,
        "inter_nat_conf": 32,
        "nat_conf": 16,
        "int_book_chap": 5,
        "nat_book_chap": 0,
        "dept_code": "102",
        "dept_name": "CSE"
    },
    "2": {
        "int_jour": 12,
        "nat_jour": 4,
        "inter_nat_conf": 10,
        "nat_conf": 23,
        "int_book_chap": 1,
        "nat_book_chap": 0,
        "dept_code": "103",
        "dept_name": "IT"
    },
    "3": {
        "int_jour": 21,
        "nat_jour": 0,
        "inter_nat_conf": 9,
        "nat_conf": 35,
        "int_book_chap": 0,
        "nat_book_chap": 0,
        "dept_code": "104",
        "dept_name": "EE"
    },
    "4": {
        "int_jour": 13,
        "nat_jour": 1,
        "inter_nat_conf": 8,
        "nat_conf": 33,
        "int_book_chap": 0,
        "nat_book_chap": 1,
        "dept_code": "105",
        "dept_name": "MCA"
    },
    "5": {
        "int_jour": 10,
        "nat_jour": 5,
        "inter_nat_conf": 12,
        "nat_conf": 13,
        "int_book_chap": 0,
        "nat_book_chap": 1,
        "dept_code": "106",
        "dept_name": "MBA"
    },
    "6": {
        "int_jour": 57,
        "nat_jour": 6,
        "inter_nat_conf": 5,
        "nat_conf": 10,
        "int_book_chap": 0,
        "nat_book_chap": 1,
        "dept_code": "109",
        "dept_name": "AS"
    },
    "7": {
        "int_jour": 0,
        "nat_jour": 0,
        "inter_nat_conf": 0,
        "nat_conf": 0,
        "int_book_chap": 0,
        "nat_book_chap": 0,
        "dept_code": "110",
        "dept_name": "CIVIL"
    }
}
```

The javascript is:

```
<script>

var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myObj.[1].dept_name;

    }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", "sss.php", true);
xmlhttp.send();

</script>
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 5):

Open your browser's developer tools. Look at the Console. Read the error messages.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [

You have:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myObj.[1].dept_name;
```

You can use dot notation **or** square bracket notation to access a property. You can't use both at the same time.

Remove the `.` before the `[`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution.